# laravel passport protecting a single route with multiple grant types as an OR statement

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Leveraging Laravel Passport ... is there a way to protect one API route with two grant types but as an OR statement and not that both need to pass?

I have been looking for some sort of solution for this but can only think of creating two separate routes - one for the "client credential grant" and the other route for the "password grant" ... which ideally I would like to just have one API route and depending on the grant type you end up using the JSON we spit back changes...

As an example if you look at the docs for the Uber API you can see they protect certain routes with both a server token and OAuth token: Server token or OAuth 2.0 user access token with any valid scope. link: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/products-get